# How to optimize complex distributed query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor, remote-server

I have a cursor in my package that uses remote DB links.
I want to optimize the performance of the package.
So I wanted to start with optimizing the cursor.

I'll give some information to analyze,

- There are no local tables in the query only remote DB links.
- The Cursor Query uses 6 Remote DB Links and performs join operations
  on them.
- All the DBlinks point to same DB but different tables.
- SELECT does not have any aggregate operations and has only NVL
  functions for few columns
- Approximately 90 Columns are being selected

The Structure of the query is

```
SELECT (SOME 90 COLUMNS)
FROM    master1_all@db_one m1,
        master2_all@db_one m2,
        prey1@db_one pa,
        prey2@db_one pb,
        prey2@db_one pc,
        tbl_abc@db_one xa,
    (SELECT
      geo.country,
      geo.state
    FROM  tb_dest@db_one geo ) geo  WHERE ( m1.master_key = m2.master_key ) AND
    ( pc.weather_key = m2.cloud_key ) AND
( m1.order_type_id = pa.weather_key ) AND
( pa.weather_key = pb.weather_key ) AND
( m2.food_store_key = xa.food_store_key ) AND
( (nvl(m2.shop_key ,121)) = xa.store_key ) AND
( geo.country (+) = m1.country ) AND
(xa.food_type NOT IN ('COLD')) AND
( m2.food_type_code NOT IN ('WINTER')
    OR m2.price_per_portion !=0 ) AND
( ( m1.last_purchase_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-10) - 1/48 And m1.last_purchase_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) ) 
Or ( m2.last_purchase_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-10) - 1/48 And m2.last_purchase_date <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) ));
```

It's not the actual query but the structure is similar.

Comment: Please post the query!

Comment: Why would you have 4 separate database links that all connect to the same database?  Do you mean that you have 4 remote objects that are each referenced using a single database link?  Can you touch the remote systems?  Is there any hope of replicating the data to your local system before processing it

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry. There's been a mistake... all the six are connecting to same database. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Try to use ANSI join syntax, it is more readable and less error prone. And why do you use so many useless brackets?

Comment: `nvl(m2.shop_key ,121) = xa.store_key` could be a bottleneck causing full-table scan on master2_all.

Comment: Is there any chance of creating a view on the remote database? If so, I'd create the above query as a view on the remote database and then simply select from the remote view from your local database.

Comment: @Boneist Yeah. I'd have done that but I don't have access.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sure. I'll remove the brackets. If NVL() could be a bottleneck, is there any other alternative?

Comment: @ArjunRaja A shame. I second Michael Piankov's suggestion of using the DRIVING_SITE hint, although whether it would work with multiple tables is another matter. Another idea is a trick that Jonathan has written about - [using a non-mergable view](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/distributed-sets/). I haven't got the time to investigate that, but maybe it will be of some use to you?

Comment: @Boneist I went through the link, it has good information but it doesn't help for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to find a bottle neck of you query. 
If problem only with executing query from remote table 
you may use hint /*+ DRIVING_SITE(...) */ https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABEGIJC  And oracle will be try to execute on remoute database

Comment: Using hints are good, but all the tables are from remote DB links.

Comment: That's why I say about `DRIVING SITE` if you use it hint oracle will try execute query (make joins, sorts, etc.) on remote database and return to you only result. In common it's faster then get any data from remote database and execute query on current site

Comment: okay. so you mean to say, I can give the hint like /*+ DRIVING_SITE(m1,m2,pa,pb,pc,xa) */

is it?

Comment: As I know that's enough specify only one alias  `/*+ DRIVING_SITE(m1) */`.

Comment: Well may be it means that executing query take not so long time, but retrieving whole set its expensive, or any other causes why it may work not so good